# [mongodb]How to save a document and automatically increase a field of it?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to save or insert a new record into my mongo database. I hope the field "userid" of it can automatically increase by 1. Is it possible to do it in mongodb?

```html
Schema
generalUserApplication: {
    userid: Number, // 1
    lora: [
       {},
       {}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way from the mongo tutorial.

You need to create new collection `counters` in your db.

```js
function getNextSequence(db, name, callback) {
    db.collection("counters").findAndModify( { _id: name }, null, { $inc: { seq: 1 } }, function(err, result){
        if(err) callback(err, result);
        callback(err, result.value.seq);
    } );
}
```

Then, you can use `getNextSequence()` as following, when you insert a new row.

```js
getNextSequence(db, "user_id", function(err, result){
    if(!err){
        db.collection('users').insert({
            "_id": result,
            // ...
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have use another package named '**mongoose-sequence-plugin**' to generate sequence which is auto-incremented by 1.
Here I am posting code that I have tried for same problem. Hope it will help.

Schema :

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var sequenceGenerator = require('mongoose-sequence-plugin');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var ProjectSchema   = new Schema({
    Name : { type : String, required: true },
    Description : { type : String, required: true },
    DetailAddress : { type : String, required: true },
    ShortAddress : { type : String, required: true },
    Latitude : { type : Number, required: true },
    Longitude : { type : Number, required: true },
    PriceMin : { type : Number, required: true, index : true },
    PriceMax : { type : Number, required: true, index: true },
    Area : { type : Number, required: true },
    City : { type : String, required: true }
});

ProjectSchema.plugin(sequenceGenerator, {
    field: 'project_id',
    startAt: '10000001',
    prefix: 'PROJ',
    maxSaveRetries: 2
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

This will create projects collection with parameter **project_id** starting from **PROJ10000001** and on wards. If you delete last inserted record then this package reads the current last entry of field project_id and next id is assigned by incrementing current id.